# How to take advantage of the new features in the newtxmath package?

Tags: newtxmath

On January 11, 2020, Michael Sharpe, author of the New TX font package, has issued a new version of the documentation of this package, in which are mentioned some new features, such as the implementation of a \mathscr command. Is it possible to add all the files involved to an existing TeX Live 2019 distribution, or me must we wait for the 2020 TeX Live issue?

Comment: Have you tried updating? I think TeXLive 2019 will be frozen at the end of this month, so you should be able to simply update `newtx` in the usual way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the user has not have update the new newtx package.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, that's rubbish.  The version of `newtxmath` that OP wants is simply not in TL2019, so there is no way to “just update”.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have done another mistake. Excuse me. Have you seen? :(